# Github API: Search only open/pending pull requests that haven't had changes requested/approved yet

Tags: api, github-api

I'm trying to get a list of open pull requests using:

`'https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=is:open+is:pr+org:myOrg+draft:false'`

But I'm also getting approved requests which isn't what I want.

```
openPrData: Array(3)
  0: {...}
  1: {...}
  2: 
    id: 77
    repo: "example"
    title: "Update example"
    author: "exampleAuthor"
    status: "open"
  

approvedPullRequests: Array(1)
  0: 
    id: 77
    repo: "example"
    title: "Update example"
    author: "exampleAuthor"
    status: "good"
```

How would I filter only requests that have yet to had changes requested or be approved?

I have looked [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-pull-request-review-status-and-reviewer) but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.